# How to filter results from another command?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep, kubectl

If have a command `kubectl get pods -n test` which lists:

```
abcd-123-ghbv
abcd-123-ghbv
abcd-123-ghbv
text-123-ghbv
abcd-123-ghbv
abcd-123-text
```

How can I use `grep` (or another command) along with the line `kubectl get pods -n test` to filter result containing `text`? The end result would be:

```
text-123-ghbv
abcd-123-text
```

I see that piping with `findstr` is one option. However I would like to do it with a native command.

Comment: Did you try `kubectl get pods -n test | grep text` ?

Comment: I was using grep wrong. This works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe using grep as follow:

```
kubectl get pods -n test | grep text
```